# How to declare limit in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have written code like this in PostgreSQL. But I'm getting error for ROWNUM

```
 EXECUTE 'SELECT BENMASTDTL_BEN_CODE FROM BENMASTDTL WHERE BENMASTDTL_ENTITY_CODE =$1 AND BENMASTDTL_CUSTOMER_CODE =$2 AND
                           BENMASTDTL_ACCOUNT_NUMBER =$3 AND BENMASTDTL_IFSC=$4 AND ROWNUM=1'
      INTO STRICT W_BENMASTDTL_BEN_CODE
          USING P_ENTITY_CODE, P_CUST_CODE, P_BEN_AC_NUM, P_BEN_IFSC;
```

error is like *column "rownum" does not exist*
please help me to solve this error

Comment: Replace `AND ROWNUM=1` with `LIMIT 1`

Comment: I have tried for limit  but getting error like.. syntax error at or near "LIMIT"

Comment: Add the corrected code to your question. Remember `AND ROWNUM=1` becomes `LIMIT 1`, there is no `AND` before `LIMIT`.

Comment: Dynamic SQL is completely useless here to begin with.